# How to export parsed json variables in docker entrypoint.sh?

Tags: bash, docker, environment-variables, docker-entrypoint

In AWS ECS, when SECRET is defined in the ECS task definition, the $SECRET variable ends up in the container as a json string.

`SECRET={"secret1":"value1","secret2":"value2"}`

I'm able to parse out and export the json string to individual environment variables when I run this command directly in the container using this command:

`eval export $(echo "$SECRET" | jq -r 'to_entries|map("\"\(.key)=\(.value|tostring)\"")|.[]' )`

But, the variables don't get set properly when I run the same command from the 'entrypoint.sh' script, on container run, when the container starts.
`["entrypoint.sh"]`

```
["entrypoint.sh"]

#!/usr/bin/env bash

if [ $# -gt 0 ];then
    ## If we passed a command in docker run, run it
    exec "$@"
else
    eval export $(echo "$SECRET" | jq -r 'to_entries|map("\"\(.key)=\(.value|tostring)\"")|.[]' ) 
 
    "${BUILD_DIR}"/run.sh
fi
```

Is it possible to parse the json string and export environment variables in an entrypoint script so that the show up in `printenv`?

Any guidance would be appreciated.

Comment: Show us your `entrypoint.sh`.

Comment: edit: added entrypoint.sh

Answer (score 0):

I tried to reproduce this problem but your code appears to work just fine. With the following Dockerfile:

```
FROM ubuntu:20.04

RUN apt-get update; apt-get -y install jq; apt-get clean all
COPY entrypoint.sh /entrypoint.sh
ENTRYPOINT ["/entrypoint.sh"]
```

And a slightly modified `entrypoint.sh`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

if [ $# -gt 0 ];then
    ## If we passed a command in docker run, run it
    exec "$@"
elif [ -n "$SECRET" ]; then
    eval export $(echo "$SECRET" | jq -r 'to_entries|map("\"\(.key)=\(.value|tostring)\"")|.[]' ) 
fi

echo "Extracted environment variables:"
env | grep '^secret'
```

If I run it like this:

```
docker build -t myimage .
docker run --rm -e 'SECRET={"secret1":"value1","secret2":"value2"}'
myimage
```

I get this output:

```
Extracted environment variables:
secret2=value3
secret1=value1
```

Your code seems to correctly extract and export to the environment the
variables encoded in the `SECRET` variable.

---

With respect to your comment, this works identically:

```
FROM ubuntu:20.04

ENV SECRET='{"secret1":"value1","secret2":"value2"}'
RUN apt-get update; apt-get -y install jq; apt-get clean all
COPY entrypoint.sh /entrypoint.sh
ENTRYPOINT ["/entrypoint.sh"]
```

And then:

```
$ docker run --rm myimage
Extracted environment variables:
secret2=value2
secret1=value1
```

Comment: It appears to work in your example above, however, if we don't pass in the secrets with the -e flag, and we change in the Dockerfile 'ENV SECRET={"secret1":"value1","secret2":"value2"}' it no longer work.

Comment: It sounds like you have an error in your `Dockerfile`. I've updated the question to address your comment.

Comment: Indeed it does, thank you for that. 

I added 'tail -f /dev/null' to the end of the entrypoint.sh to keep the container up, then 'docker exec' into the running container. When when I run 'env', the SECRET var shows up but not the extracted vars. Also, echo "$secret1" returns an empty value.  I don't think the entrypoint is running the export command in the main process.

Answer (score 0):

The sort of complex variable manipulation you're describing is hard to do in a shell script, but much more straightforward in other languages.  There's really only two requirements around an entrypoint wrapper script: it must be executable given the language runtime and libraries in the image, and it must execute the command passed to it as parameters.

So you could imagine writing a Python entrypoint wrapper script, for example.  Modifying [`os.environ`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.environ) modifies the environment in the same way as the shell `export` built-in; [`os.execvp()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.execvp) replaces the current process with a new one, like the shell `exec` built-in.  If you're doing this already then you can use the standard [`json`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html) library for JSON parsing.

This leads to a script like:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# entrypoint.py

import json
import os

# Set arbitrary environment variables from a JSON-encoded
# $SECRET environment variable
if 'SECRET' in os.environ:
  for k, v in json.loads(os.environ['SECRET']).items():
    os.environ[k] = v

# Get the command to run from command-line arguments
cmd = sys.argv[1:]
if len(cmd) == 0:
  cmd = [os.path.join(os.environ['BUILD_DIR']), "run.sh"]

# Replace this script with that command.
os.execvp(cmd[0], cmd)
```

So long as your image already has a Python interpreter and you mark this script as executable, you can use it as an `ENTRYPOINT ["./entrypoint.py"]` the same way you do your existing shell script.